# Unable to access locally hosted sites from local network

Tags: networking, apache2

I have configured apache2 to use a couple of virtual hosts and am running ddclient to push the dynamic IP to the hostname provider.  I have the ports open on my firewall/router and all of this is working fine **as long as I'm on an external network**.
When I'm operating on my local network I can access the sites from the server using the local IP or the name which is set in `/etc/hosts`.  The problem is that from any other machine on the network I simply get a connection refused when trying to access via the external IP.  I have searched through both router and server logs trying to find the reason for denial but I cannot find anything other than a simple 'Invalid State' in the router log so I'm not sure it's even related (sorry if it's a red herring).
I have disabled the local firewall on the server for testing and still no access.

For what it's worth, I'm on AT&T and did find [this discussion](https://forums.att.com/t5/U-verse-2014-Archive/DNS-Cache-AT-amp-T-side/td-p/4035842) that appears related.

> However, when attempting to access the website stricly over Uverse,
>   it's not responding.  I've worked with the Host provider and determind
>   that this is an issue with AT&T's DNS Cache, as we've flushed
>   everything on our end.

There's also [another response](http://ask.metafilter.com/56291/Why-do-I-still-see-our-old-website-even-though-the-DNS-should-have-had-plenty-of-time-to-propagate) that another had related to their work network but the symptoms were the same.

> Ok, so the problem is that you can't see your website from the local
>   network, but you can everywhere else. That probably means that your
>   local DNS server believes it is authoritative for that zone, and it
>   has the old address in its zone file. If you're using the exact same
>   domain name for your ... website, that's absolutely the problem.

Any advice or direction on where to go next would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the virtual hosts accessible directly through the WAN (as in each receives it's own respective WAN IP) or do you have Port Forwarding/NAT setup?

Comment: port forwarding is enabled via the router

Comment: if you do nslookup for sites does it resolve to your WAN IP?

Comment: Yes it does resolve.  I had verified the IP at the provider in the A+ records match that known by my router

Answer (score 0):

If you have manually created an A record in router's DNS for the site to the WAN IP, then when you attempt to get to those sites, it's routing you to your routers WAN IP. If you're behind the router, you won't be able to get to any host/site that resolves to the WAN IP of the router. If you have port forwarding setup for the Apache server, then you shouldn't need to statically assign an A record for each site. Assign port forwarding for http(s) traffic on the WAN interface to point to your Apache server on the LAN. This will allow you resolve the IP internally when you're on the network, and resolve it externally when you're out. If you have more than one Apache servers for the same site, then you need to setup NAT not a port forward, as most non-commercial routers won't let you forward the same port to multiple destinations.

Comment: I did not manually create the A+ record.  It was created through the use of the dynamic client as it pushed my IP to the provider.  Or is this your definition of "manual"?

Comment: Yeah, same concept. The result is the same, if your site resolves to the router's WAN IP on your computer when you're behind that router, you're not going to be able to get to it.

Comment: The A+ records are created by the domain provider but also exist because of my dynamic IP updates.  Without them how would external requests locate the server?  I've already taken care of the port forwarding on the WAN to point to the apache server.